# Location Tracking: Native or web application

Tags: android, geolocation

I would like to build an Android app that will detect and log the position co-ordinates to database. 
I want to compare the results of native and web application on the following criterias

1) Location accuracy
2) Application performance
3) Application maintenance
4) Development time

I am a web developer and familiar with HTML and PhoneGap framework.
Please suggest me whether I should go for native or web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you know more about web app than me; for native app:

I actually am working on a similar project. [Here](https://github.com/yyl/Tracking-map-on-android) is my code for location tracking on android; check it out. It tracks user's location regularly, uses Network location while indoor, and GPS when it could have a fix. It should give you a quick start.

Also, google has an open source project called [My Tracks](http://www.google.com/mobile/mytracks/), which has a better performance but has more complex code. You also look into that.

Comment: Thanks Yulong. I think location tracking should be an native application for better location accuracy and performance.

Comment: @HemantKamalakar yeah, that is exactly what I am doing for my project, native android app.